# Автозагрузка от имени администратора(Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

имеется прога на питоне, которая запускается пользователем от имени администратор единожды, а затем прописывается в автозапуске(в реестре).Проблема в том, что при загрузке системы, она не запускается от имени администратора. Могли бы предложить решения, как можно запустить программу от имени администратора без подтверждения пользователя, не зная пароль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надеюсь вы делаете не вирус. На другом форуме нашел такое решение. Если оно вам не поможет, можете попробовать сделать упаковщик через `winrar` или `7-zip` и выставить галочку где запрос прав администратора.
(запихнуть в поле код не получилось, поэтому даю ссылку https://www.cyberforum.ru/python-api/thread2640424.html)

Answer (score 1):

Можно с помощью pyinstaller(программа по упаковке py в exe).Просто напишите:

```
pyinstaller --uac-admin "имя файла"
```